# Count not working properly. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to count number of files attached in my forms.
Following is my html code.

```
<label class="control-label">Select Images</label>
<input id="image" name="image[]" multiple type="file">
```

I have used following to count.

```
return count($request->file('image'));
```

The problem i'm facing is, it is showing 1 even if no file has been attached.

What can be done to check if no file has been attached?

Comment: how many inputs you have ?

Comment: When i select none it shows 1. When i select 1 it shows 1. WHen i select 2 it shows 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return count($request->image);` is returning 1  because `$request->image` gives an empty string "" even with no file selected. You can count only values that are not empty in array using 
[array_filer()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```
return  count(array_filter($request->image));
```

You may determine if a file is present on the request using the
 hasFile method. Remember, file method is used for uploaded files not only selected.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
return empty($request->file('image'));
```

Comment: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `hasFile()` method of the `Request` class? It'll tell you whether a file has been uploaded or not

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_hasFile

Comment: I actually have no idea how to implement this. Can you give an example?

Comment: Calling `$request->hasFile('image')` will give you a `true` (if there's a file) or `false` (otherwise)